# How to show Fab on a RelativeLayout in a Tab Layout

Tags: java, android

I have a tab layout that shows a relative layout on one of the tabs, I want this particular tab to show a fab at the bottom. When I add the fab to the layout design view it shows but when I test on a device the fab "disappears" - does not show at all"

Here is my tab items relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/compose_query_content_linear_layout"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/query_subject_editText"
    android:hint="@string/query_subject_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/query_content_editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/query_subject_editText"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/compose_query_content_text"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/query_floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_notifications_busket"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:borderWidth="4dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@color/muzima_theme_blue" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my tabs parent layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/message_basket_main_activity_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/message_basket_main_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/message_basket_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/muzima_theme_blue"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="phr.muzima.org.phr.MessageBasketMainActivity">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/message_basket_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here my fragment activity.java

```
package phr.muzima.org.phr.fragments;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import phr.muzima.org.phr.R;
import phr.muzima.org.phr.adapters.UpdatesAdapter;
import phr.muzima.org.phr.model.Update;

 /**
  * Created by HP on 1/19/2018.
 */

 public class PatientQueriesFragment extends Fragment {

  FloatingActionButton fab;

public PatientQueriesFragment() {

}

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
  container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_queries_fragment_layout, 
     container, false);
    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.query_floatingActionButton);

    return view;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue myself and found that using coordinator layout worked well for FABs. Put the FAB on this layout and then the relative layout like you have as normal.

Comment: which layout specifically?

Comment: @samuelowino Put your coordinator layout at the top of your layout file and put your FAB in this. Then add remove your FAB from the relative layout and add the relative layout as a child of the coordinator layout. Let me know if this works or I will use Android Studio and fix it myself.